# Jasmin-Karma and mocking localStorage spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for getItem()

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am currently evolving into TDD and want to test my `AuthController`. Inside my controller there is a service being injected, called `AuthService`. This service uses $localStorage, respectively the `ngstorage` bower package. I want to mock it in order to test my controller. I did so by using `SpyOn` provided by `jasmine`. As browser I use phantomjs. Unfortunately I am getting this error message by jasmine-core:

```
Error: spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for getItem()
```

**auth.controller.spec.coffee**:

```
describe 'AuthController', ->

  AuthController = undefined
  scope = undefined
  localStorage = undefined

  beforeEach ->
    module('myApp')
    store = {}
    spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').andCallFake (key) ->
      store[key]
    spyOn(localStorage, 'setItem').andCallFake (key, value) ->
      store[key] = value + ''

  beforeEach inject(($controller, $rootScope, _AuthService_) ->
    scope = $rootScope.$new()
    AuthService = _AuthService_
    AuthController = $controller('AuthController', $scope: scope, AuthService:AuthService)
  )

  it 'verifies AuthService is injected', ->
    expect(scope.AuthService).to.have.property 'email'

  it 'verifies signIn is working', ->
    scope.AuthService.set('email', 'john@doe.com')
    expect(scope.AuthService.email) .to.equal 'john@doe.com'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access a service without injecting it. The calls to `spyOn()` should be inside the second `beforeEach`, and the service should be injected, in order to be able to spy on its methods:

```
  beforeEach ->
    module('myApp')
    store = {}


  beforeEach inject(($controller, $rootScope, _AuthService_, localStorage) ->
    scope = $rootScope.$new()
    AuthService = _AuthService_
    spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').andCallFake (key) ->
      store[key]
    spyOn(localStorage, 'setItem').andCallFake (key, value) ->
      store[key] = value + ''
    AuthController = $controller('AuthController', $scope: scope, AuthService:AuthService)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks so far. I amended my code and now I am getting: `1) "before each" hook: workFn
     AuthController
     Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: localStorageProvider <- localStorage`. I guess I still have to mock the localStorage service?

Comment: If the module you're using is that one: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage, then the service is named $localStorage, and not localStorage.

Comment: Again, thanks for the hint. I am seeing not `getItem() method does not exist`

Comment: Well, as documented in the README of this module, there is indeed no getItem function in $localStorage. You write a value using $localStorage.foo = 'hello', and you read it using $localStorage.foo. So you don't have any getItem function to spy on.

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers and debugging. Still so far I am failing to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a better way to do this than to use the `$provide` module in Jasmine to mock the `$localStorage` service as an object, since this service doesn't have any getter or setter. I was not able to use Jasmine spies in the mock, so what I did was to provide the object with the inner properties needed by the service that consumes the `$localStorage` service.

```
describe("serviceThatUsengStorage", function() {
    "use strict";

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    var $serviceToTest;
    var $localStorage = {};
    var user = {
        uname: 'andre',
        pass: 'andre_pass'
    };

    beforeEach(function() {
        $localStorage.user = user;
        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('$localStorage', $localStorage);
        });
    });

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_serviceToTest_) {
        $serviceToTest = _serviceToTest_;
    }));

    it("the serviceThatUsengStorage must be initilizaded using the localStorage", function() {
        expect($serviceToTest).not.toBe(null);
        expect($serviceToTest.getUserName()).toBe('andre');
        expect($serviceToTest.getUserPass()).toBe('andre_pass');
    });


});
```

You can see a very good example in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK-Z0oEdE4Y).